# nodejs background task

Tags: node.js

Been playing around with node.js and I am developing a file uploading web app as a learning experience. Now I have worked out most components of this apart from 1. Which is after a successful file upload in to a quarantine folder after a upload is complete I want to spawn off a independent process in node.js which scans the file and moves file if clean. In the mean time I wish for the upload to return a response that file was successful and to tell them that it will take a few minuets for scan to finish.

How would I go about spawning such a background process in node js please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well maybe [Kue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/kue) is the solution, here's a nice video tutorial about it: http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/27-kue-jobs.html

Basically in your main app you put some tasks in the queue, and in the other process you execute them based on priority (it's ok since you don't want them to be executed right away).

Also I this is a lot better than spawning a process per each file upload.

Answer (score -1):

Everything in node is asynchronous, so if you want to keep it within the same node app, just use the [asynchronous file system methods](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html). Use the methods **without** `sync` in their names. Those methods return immediately so your script can continue.

Comment: Keep it in the same app? What if 100 users upload files in the same time that need to be than scaned and moved, so the event loop blocks, thus slowing the entire app down?

Comment: just had a look wouldn't the ones such as the watcher require a file system event to take place? You see the I only want to trigger it when the file upload is complete as the client may send it by xhr or in chunks of 2mb by using pluploader. Now pluploader when doing the chunk mode will post what chunk it is upto and how many chunks there is in total.

Comment: You can use the file system event to queue a job for later execution, indeed, but you still want to keep the scanning, moving etc in a separate process (so that it doesn't block the whole site for the rest of your users). That's why I said Kue would fit here.

Comment: im not wanting to use redis as a database however I will be picking apart the kue and adapting it